# How to classify ODE equilibria that are stable but slowly changing in value with time?

Tags: ode, stability, differential-equations, jacobian

I'm numerically solving a system of coupled ODEs where time is the independent variable. At each time, I can solve for the equilibrium values of my state variables where their respective derivatives go to zero and classify the equilibria as stable or unstable. For one of my variables, the equilibrium value is stable at all times but gradually changes with time. My actual solution also tends to stay near this equilibrium -- i.e., my solution variable also gradually changes in value to keep up with the stable equilibrium.

My question is: what is the formal classification name for this kind of equilibrium? The best I can come up with is a wordy description: the equilibrium is "locally stable" (at any given time, a perturbation away from it would bring the variable toward the equilibrium) but at the same time also "globally unstable" since the equilibrium value is not constant in time but rather evolving. I should say that after evolving the system for a long time, the equilibrium does become constant with time so in the end it is also "asymptotically stable". Just wondering if I am using these equilibrium/stability classification terms correctly.

Comment: Just to clarify, it sounds like your system is non-autonomous, i.e. it has the form $\dot x = f(x, t)$ where the right-hand side explicitly depends on $t$ -- is that correct? A lot of the stability theory you see assumes that the system is autonomous, i.e. you can write it as $\dot x = f(x)$ with no dependence on $t$.

Comment: Ok, here is an example of such system: Water in a bathtub settles down on flat surface, but the surface height slowly drops due to a small leak in the bathtub. This is a typical problem with a large separation of time scales, and there is no formal classification for those other than saying that the eigenvalues are very disparate in size (by absolute value). The large ones correspond to fast dynamics (waves on the surface etc.) which happen here to be stable (negative imaginary parts). But one could have a situation with unstable water surface (Rayleigh-Taylor) and slowly evolving water level.

Comment: What you are describing is similar to (but different from) the concept of a [center manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_manifold).